# Динамический массив наследников базового класса

Tags: c++

Есть класс Shape и его производные классы Square и Circle. Мне нужно создать динамический массив элементов Square и Circle.

Я знаю, что чтобы обратиться к методу производного класса через его базовый класс нужно обращаться к методу по ссылке ну то есть вот так:

```
Shape* test = new Circle(10);
cout << test->GetArea() << endl;
```

В статическом массиве все просто получается `Shape* arr[2];`

Но как сделать динамический массив?

Вот код класса Shape, Square, Circle:

```
    class Shape {
public:
    string nameShape;
    virtual double GetPerimeter() { return 0; }
    virtual double GetArea() { return 0; }
};

class Square : public Shape {
private:
    double length;
public:
    Square(double a) : length(a) {
        nameShape = "Квадрат";
    }
    virtual double GetPerimeter() {
        return 4 * length;
    }
    virtual double GetArea() {
        return length * length;
    }
};

class Circle : public Shape {
private:
    double radius;
    const double PI = 3.1415926;
public:
    Circle(double r) : radius(r) {
        nameShape = "Окружность";
    }
    virtual double GetPerimeter() {
        return 2 * PI * radius;
    }
    virtual double GetArea() {
        return PI * radius * radius;
    }
};
```

**ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ:**

Вот вроде придумал как можно сделать, но точно не знаю правильно ли. (Зато работает) )

```
Shape** arr = new Shape*[2];
arr[0] = new Square(10);
arr[1] = new Circle(10);
for (int i = 0; i < 2; ++i) {
    cout << arr[i]->GetArea() << endl;
    delete arr[i];
}
delete[] arr;
```

Comment: Все правильно сделали, только недостает виртуального деструктора у `Shape`. Хотя лучше, конечно, использовать `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Shape>>`...

Comment: @HolyBlackCat вот насчет виртуального деструктора. У меня же нет в классе данных под которые выделяется память через оператор new.

Comment: Сейчас проблем из-за этого быть не должно, но если такие поля появятся, его очень легко забыть добавить. Да и формально, удаление объекта через указатель на родителя, у которого нет виртуального деструктора, вызывает неопределенное поведение.

Answer (score 0):

Для начала - у тебя массив указателей на Shape а не на сами объекты и по этому указателю ты вызываешь виртуальную функцию.
А так можно спокойно использовать любой стандартный контейнер, например std::vector

Comment: Не понял, что вы имели ввиду под `у тебя массив указателей на Shape, а не сами объекты` если мне чтобы обращаться к методам класса наследника через базовый класс как раз и нужно использовать указатель. И на счет std::vector я знал просто для саморазвития все это делаю

Comment: Имеется в виду, что в принципе возможен массив объектов `Shape`, но статический. Динамический массив объектов разного размера создать не выйдет. Потому единственный вариант - как Вы и сделали. И для саморазвития как раз лучше забыть о двойных указателях и выделению памяти через new.